# BIRT Report Designer Computed Column

Tags: sql, mariadb, birt

I would like to check on BIRT Report Designer. How can I create a computed column for below?

Column A  values are A, B and C and
Column B  values are 0.25, 0.33 and 0.21

I will need the result for

sum of Column B / number of rows at column A which translates to
(0.25+0.33+0.21)/3

I have tried in SQL only, but not sure how to do this in BIRT

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following expression as part of a data element that has a binding to row B of a dataset that provides your data:

```
Total.sum(dataSetRow["B"]) / Total.count(dataSetRow["B"]);
```

The report will evaluate that expression to 0,263 with your sample data. A minimal BIRT Report template with a Scripted Data Source that provides your example data is in the following, which could be saved as .rptdesign file and opened in the BIRT Report Designer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.24" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.13.0.v202303021806</property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
    <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
    <property name="imageDPI">96</property>
    <data-sources>
        <script-data-source name="scriptedDataSource" id="4525"/>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <script-data-set name="getSampleData" id="4543">
            <list-property name="resultSetHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                    <property name="name">A</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">2</property>
                    <property name="name">B</property>
                    <property name="dataType">decimal</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <list-property name="columnHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">A</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">A</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">B</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">B</text-property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">A</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">2</property>
                        <property name="name">B</property>
                        <property name="dataType">decimal</property>
                    </structure>
                </list-property>
            </structure>
            <property name="dataSource">scriptedDataSource</property>
            <method name="open"><![CDATA[count = 0;
colA = ["A","B","C"];
colB = [0.25, 0.33, 0.21];]]></method>
            <method name="fetch"><![CDATA[if(count < 3){    
    row["A"] = colA[count];
    row["B"] = colB[count];
        
    count++;
    return true;
}
return false;


]]></method>
        </script-data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <page-setup>
        <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
            <page-footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <property name="contentType">html</property>
                    <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                </text>
            </page-footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </page-setup>
    <body>
        <data id="4562">
            <property name="dataSet">getSampleData</property>
            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">A</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">A</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["A"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">B</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">B</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["B"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">decimal</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">SumA_div_by_countB</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">SumB_div_by_countB</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">result = "";&#13;
try {&#13;
    result = Total.sum(dataSetRow["B"]) / Total.count(dataSetRow["B"]);&#13;
}&#13;
catch (error) {&#13;
    result = error;&#13;
}&#13;
result;</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    <property name="allowExport">true</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <property name="resultSetColumn">SumA_div_by_countB</property>
        </data>
    </body>
</report>
```